# Count Business Days when date is between input

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

I have two tables in excel 2016.

First Tab Associates:

```
 hire_dt      Term_dt         id
 06/25/2018    09/10/2018    101
```

Second tab Input Assumptions:

```
   First Date of month (row b4)  last Date of month (row b5)  Business Days (row b7)
      9/1/2018                   09/30/2018                         20
```

Criteria:

1. Term date IS NULL AND hire_dt <= "First Date of month" THEN 100
2. hire_dt >= "First Date of month" and "Term_dt" between "First Date of month" & "last Date of month" THEN business days between hire_dt and term_dt / business days (row b7)
3. hire_dt >= "First Date of month" and term_dt is null THEN business days between hire_dt and "First Date of month / business days (row by)
4. hire_dt < = "First Date of month" and term_dt between First Date of month and last Date of month, business days between between "First Date of month" and term_dt / Business Days (row b7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you didn't use any question marks in your post, it is not that easy to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve.

But, I believe, you can manage to get that by combination of nested `IF()`'s and translating your conditions into [`EOMONTH()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-7314FFA1-2BC9-4005-9D66-F49DB127D628) and [`WORKDAY()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-function-F764A5B7-05FC-4494-9486-60D494EFBF33) language.